# Allure and code coverage reports

Tags: code-coverage, allure

Is there any way to integrate code coverage tools output (like **Cobertura**) with Allure test reports?
I have already integrated Allure with JUnit to build reports for functional testing. But I have no idea how to build code coverage reports in the same way.

Comment: Which kind of integration you need?

Comment: Cobertura reports are hard to read for the testers. And Allure reports are very users frendly. So I want to find some Allure adapter for Cobertura or something like that.

Answer (score 2):

As you say Cobertura is **code coverage tool** with its own report. Allure it's **test report tool**. Seems like it's incompatible things.